# yt:quota too many recent calls - Youtube API help

Tags: api, youtube

I am using youtube api to get contents from a youtube account (with
just user feed...without user authentication) on our website.
Since yesterday morning, we keep getting:

```
<error>
    <domain>yt:quota</domain>
    <code>too_many_recent_calls</code>
</error>
```

It started off as a random occurrence, but very soon, we get this error 100% of the time.
I tried the following [quota limits instructions](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/faq.html#quota) but I still get the error:

> If you are receiving quota errors,
>   there are a couple steps you can take:
>
> - Have your requests include your developer key and clientID. **I do this**
> - Make sure the actions your code is performing is user-initiated. **I do
>     this**
> - Pass the user's IP address in the restriction query parameter. **I am able
>     to pass only the proxy/server IP
>     address, not the exact client's
>     because Google AppEngine does not
>     support
>     InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress())**
> - If you are requesting authenticated feeds, login as the user rather than a
>     site-wide account. **I am not using
>     authentication**

Comment: Update: Tried this on local & everything is working perfectly irrespective of any number of youtube calls. Problem occurs once i upload it to goggle app engine.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with Youtube API + App-Engine. I was passing the developer-key as parameter of the request, as well as the other suggested parameters (user-ip, developer-key in the request url) and still didn't work with App Engine.

Well it seemed that the developer key wasn't getting through (although X-Gdata-key was present in the POST request headers). I've found this solution:

Every YouTubeService instance has the attributes **developer_key** and **client_id**. Setting this attributes when creating the service instance (instead of setting the 'X-GData-Key' in the headers or the **key** attribute of a query instance) makes the **developer_key** for the app id: **client_id** to be sent in every request, and accepted successfully.

You can set these values in the [constructor of YouTubeService for the Java API](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/youtube/YouTubeService.html).

If you are using the API for Python, you can set the parameters directly as following:

```
client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    client.client_id = <application_id>
    client.developer_key = <developer_key>
```

I noticed that my developer_key wasn't getting through by checking the stats on the YouTube API dashboard.

Comment: @Javiefdr: Just saying that it worked for me *so far*, I'm at 115K entries downloaded, and still going.  Previously, I was limited to about 15K entries before getting a `403 Forbidden` response.

Answer (score 2):

While re-building the wheel for youtube api with python, I found what might have caused the `X-GData-Key` unrecognizable. This answers @Javierfdr .

Short answer: `urllib2` is doing `.capitalize()` and `.title()` all over and mess up the headers.

There are bunch of those code all over in the `urllib2` module. Some in handlers and some in `Request`. `X-GData-Key` is converted into `X-Gdata-Key` (*titled*, note the lower *d*), or `X-gdata-key` (when *capitalized*). I had to build a custom HTTPSHandler and a Request object just to comment out the lines.

I'm not sure why they do this, but a long thread talks about this issue in http://bugs.python.org/issue2275 . I guess it didn't make it to python 2.7.

I tried out the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/), and it didn't mess up it with headers. Hooray :)

Just so that others would not waste their time, or at least have a clue what's happening.

-- edit --

Actually, I found out the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2) states the header field names are case-insensitive, and I couldn't find out any evidence that google doesn't. I was wrong about the statement below, I still don't get any stats :( Sorry to be misleading.

> After changing all of them, I finally saw the stats in YouTube API
> dashboard - always wondered why there was no data until now.