# Google app engine Youtube API

Tags: google-app-engine, youtube

We have a small YoutubeAPI mashup App hosted on Google App engine. From last friday; we have been getting yt:quota - too_many_recent_calls error from youtube even though we call once in an hour. We suspected Google App engine; and hosted our war to some hosting provider & it was Rock Solid & we are NOT getting those youtube quota limit errors (too_many_recent_calls). Unable to understand why we are getting that error only when we host on Google App engine . Are there any problems with Google App engine from the last few days?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
-Satish

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed these guidelines: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/faq.html#quota

If not, your requests might not be seen as separate from all the other youtube api requests originating on appengine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using YouTube API + App Engine. I suggest you to check my answer to a very similar question in the following post: [yt:quota too many recent calls - Youtube API help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035391/ytquota-too-many-recent-calls-youtube-api-help/4651335#4651335)