# Calling youtube api from gae app returns 403

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube-api

I'm trying to call the following URL to get the returned JSON using Python:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pbsnewshour/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc&prettyprint=true
```

But all I got is:

```
 File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

I need to add that I switched on the YouTube Analytics API and YouTube Data API v3 services for the gae app.

this is the code i use on the python side:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
response = urllib2.urlopen( req )
dump = response.read()
d = json.loads(dump)
```

In local everything works fine.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the 403 code, what's content of your http request?

I tried your API url in my browser with a proxy hosted on GAE, I got a 403 too, with the following XML content.

```
<error>
    <domain>yt:quota</domain>
    <code>too_many_recent_calls</code>
</error>
```

I guess GAE's urlfetch service is hosted on some individual servers. Many gae app instances share the same urlfetch server with the ip. So it is very easy for a GAE app to reach Youtube's call number limit for each ip.

There are some workarounds in this SO post: [yt:quota too many recent calls - Youtube API help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035391/ytquota-too-many-recent-calls-youtube-api-help). But it seems that they did not solve the problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

You should include a developer-key in your requests, you can register for one [here](https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues going on here. First of all, because you switched on YouTube Data API v3 services, you should be using v3 of the API; however, the URL you're requesting in your example is for v2 of the API. The endpoint you'll want to use for v3 that corresponds to this is here:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&playlistId=UU6ZFN9Tx6xh-skXCuRHCDpQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Secondly, as another post mentions, you'll want to use an API key with your request; for v3 of the API, you can do so in the [Google API console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) (or their new [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/console#/project)) where you'll generate what they call a "Browser Key" for your app. Append that in the relevant place in the endpoint, and you should get back the JSON you're interested in.

Finally, you may be wondering where the long string came from used as the parameter for the playlistId in the request URL I mentioned above; in v3 of the API, you can do a request to a user's 'channels' endpoint like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&forUsername=pbsnewshour&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

And you will have returned to you various feeds relating to that user; the string I extracted from there us the 'uploads' feed, so it corresponds to what you were looking for in your original post.